# Send thread to background

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to implement a music player.
I wrote a class which extends from Thread and overwrote its Start()-Method to play a random song.

Playing a song works, but I want to send that thread to the background, which doesn't work:

```
File file = new File("song.mp3");
PlayEngine plengine = new PlayEngine(); //This class extends from Thread

plengine.Play(file); //This just sets the file to play in a variable
plengine.Start(); //And this finally plays the file itself

System.out.println("Next task:"); // I don't get to this point. Only when the song has finished.
```

As you can see in the code above, I'd like to go to the printed line right after launching the thread.

Comment: show us the code inside `Start()` method of yours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not recommended to extend `Thread` - Have your `PlayEngine` implement `Runnable` instead, and override the `run` method:

```
class PlayEngine implements Runnable {
    private final File file;

    PlayEngine(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do your stuff here
        play(file);
    }
}
```

Then start the tread with:

```
PlayEngine plengine = new PlayEngine(file);
Thread t = new Thread(plengine);
t.start();
System.out.println("Next task:");
```

and `Next task` should print immediately. In your example, you seem to be calling the long running method `play` in the main thread, which explains why it does not return immediately.

Comment: And call those functions Play(), etc in the start() method.

Comment: But OP is extending from Thread so any way code should work fine.

Comment: @Brady Yes I have amended that.

Comment: @AmitD I suspect that the problem is due to calling `Play` on the main thread.

Comment: @assylias ahhh now the solution makes a lot of sense :)

Comment: @assylias, yes the OP was just calling methods on his thread class, but not actually doing anything multi threaded

Comment: @QKL Try using conditional variables.

Comment: @QKL assylias knows everything ;) to pause a thread you can use `Thread.sleep(long miliseconds)`. Or you can use `wait-notify mechanism`

Comment: @QKL There are many ways - it depends on why you want to pause it and how you want to wake it up. Assuming you want to be able to pause and resume playing on demand, a `volatile boolean paused` flag would possibly be sufficient. If your use case is more complicated, you could ask a separate, specific question about it.

Comment: It's a song which is played. I want to pause it on an event.

Answer (score 2):

> overwrote its `Start()`

I suspect you overriden `Thread.start()` which will never work. Either override `Thread.run()` or supply your own instance of `Runnable` to thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pring the log PlayEngine's run method very first. Moreover It appears you have written the playback code in start method(which runs in main thread) instead of run method. To get the playback done in background put the code in start in run method by overriding that.