# Commands after a Thread is started aren't executed

Tags: java

I did a little client server application in Java on LinuxOS, where the server receives different commands from the client and processes them by starting different threads. There is one specific thread for each command.

My main-program starts a thread, that responds to different commands and consists simplified of one infinite loop. There is no exit out of the loop yet. This Thread prints to the Terminal, where the main-program was started, but the commands after ".start()" aren't executed.

```
ServerSend servSend = new ServerSend(arg);
System.out.println("1"); 
servSend.start();
System.out.println("2");`
```

So "2" is never printed, whereas some "System.out.println()" inside the thread work. Does anybody have an idea why?

Comment: What is `ServerSend`? Does `start()` return?

Comment: Are you by any chance extend `Thread` and override `start()`?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz Yet another way of abusing Thread I hadn't thought of ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I didn't as well, until I saw [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099610) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to spawn a new thread, I assume `ServerSend` implements `java.lang.Runnable` or extends `java.lang.Thread` in which case you should be overwriting the `public void run()` method, **not** the `start()` method.

ie:

```
public class ServerSend implements java.lang.Runnable {
    public Thread thread;
    public ServerSend(arg) {
        //constructor
        thread = new Thread(this);
    }
    public void run() {
        //the contents of this method are executed in their own thread
    }
}
```

And then use it with;

```
ServerSend s = new ServerSend(arg);
s.thread.start();
```

Public access to `thread` allows you to do things like;

```
s.thread.interrupt();
```

This is my preferred method (using `Runnable`) others prefer to extend `Thread`. This answer pretty much sums up my thinking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/541506/980520

Comment: He didn't write he overwrote start instead of run.